# Java Split string into words commas and full stops

Tags: java, regex, split

I have been using `myString.split("\\s+");` to get the each word. But now I want to split the commas and full stops aswell. For Example:

> Mama always said life was like a box of chocolates, you never know what you're gonna get.

to:

```
{Mama, always, said, life, was, like, a, box, of, chocolates ,,, You, never, know, what, you're, gonna, get,.,}
```

How would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If commas and periods are always followed by whitespace or end-of-string, then you can write:

```
myString.split("(?=[,.])|\\s+");
```

If they're not and you want e.g. `a,b` to be split into three strings, then:

```
myString.split("(?<=[,.])|(?=[,.])|\\s+");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to split before dots and commas, too:

```
myString.split("\\s+|(?=[,.])");
```

That the lookahead is not included in the actual match, so the actual character (comma or period) will end up in the resultant array.

Comment: @JackBilbo well it's the same solution ;). But go ahead and accept ruakh's answer, seeing his second solution also takes care of cases where there is no space after a comma or period.